# ng build --prod: Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript, single-page-application

I was building an Angular 4 and it runs completely fine in the developer server and without the `--prod` flag but as soon as I ran `ng build --prod` on My Angular 4 Project but it gives the following output:

PS: It's built using ng cli version 1.4.2

Variable that is giving error:

```
userHotelLength = '0';
```

Output:

```
Date: 2018-01-24T17:25:24.719Z                                                        
Hash: a7059ea62cc4eeb37fde
Time: 12033ms
chunk {0} styles.c9da94e47a8635066285.bundle.css (styles) 142 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} polyfills.3bc34265385d52184eab.bundle.js (polyfills) 86 bytes {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} main.e402deade8b026b7d50e.bundle.js (main) 84 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} inline.9d07561b59257af76b95.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in ng:///home/x/y/z.html (10,6): Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.
ERROR in ng:///home/x/y/z.html (29,6): Operator '!=' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.
ERROR in ng:///home/x/y/z.html (36,6): Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.
```

Code:

```
<div class="my-booking-card loading-card" *ngIf="userHotelLength == 0 && (!userCancelledHotels || !userBookedHotels)">
...
</div>
<div *ngIf="userHotelLength != 0 && (userCancelledHotels || userBookedHotels)">

...

</div>

<div class="no-hotel-found" *ngIf="userHotelLength == 0">
...
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better than the error message

Comment: Can you set `userHotelLength: number = 0;`?

Comment: My guess is that it's not allowing you to coercively compare a string with a number. Try setting `userHotelLength = 0`, not "0" and see if that fixes things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare one type with other with *AOT* it gives error because it compiles at the time of build.

I your change variables type it will worked. You won't get idea until you compile code with AOT because at the development one generally don't serve with AOT.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

Change the variable type to any instead of string because we're comparing right:

```
userHotelLength: any = '0';
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `number` type?

Comment: Is there a good reason you are using coercive equality? Why does userHotelLength need to be a string? FYI `'' == 0; // true`

Comment: @mhodges well, idk at that time the api returned a string.